# Why are clicks in query keywords and pages inconsistent?

Tags: google-search-console

In google search console/performance, I see zero click under query keywords section, but some clicks under pages section(some pages got clicked). I think the number of clicks should be the same. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

There could potentially be several reasons, but the most likely one was written up by Ahrefs earlier this year. Apparently, they found that [keywords were hidden for 46% of Google Search Console clicks](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/hidden-keywords-gsc-ahrefs-study/455615/).

Here's some of the relevant info:

“Google gives a few reasons for this discrepancy:

- Privacy
- Queries made a small number of times

I doubt that many are for privacy, so that leaves a lot of long-tail queries that Google isn’t exposing to website owners and SEOs.”

With privacy being a popular conversation going on in the industry right now, I would not be surprised if it actually is one of the reasons, though.

They also found that the hidden data is very likely to be the case with lowest (as well as highest) traffic websites. Your question says that "some pages got clicked," so I'm guessing your website traffic might fall into this category.